# Android actionbar menu items

Tags: android

I want to display a menu item 'refresh' in action bar (always shown). Other two menu items 'logout' and 'help' to displayed only when menu item is pressed. My menu xml file is

list.xml

```
   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:title="@string/logout"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    />
 <item 
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="@string/help"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    />
```

The problem is when I press menu button, it displays 'help' and 'logout' options. But again when I press menu button it gets added i.e it shows two refresh button on action bar and two logout and help buttons on pressing menu. It multiplies as I press menu button. Please help me!

My onCreateOptions:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_refresh:
                refreshing();
                break;
        case R.id.logout:
                logOutActivity();
                break;
        case R.id.help:
                helpActivity();
                break;
      }
      return false;       
      }
```

In my app I display another menu when a checkbox is clicked hence I used onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(buttonChecked==true)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listmenu, menu);
    }
    else
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);

    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: show your full code..

Comment: still i cant help from this code.

Comment: I removed onPrepareOptionsMenu() and added the code in onCreateOptionsMenu() itself. It works perfectly                                   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

if(buttonChecked==true)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listmenu, menu);
    }
    else
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);

    }
    return true;

}

Comment: @Segi Thanks for contributing to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in this line. return your menu.

```
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
```